# Row number in sql having issue with generating

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I am facing one issue in below query

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp(rowid int,settle_id int)
insert into #tmp
select top 100 
case when row_number() over (order by settle_id) > 10 then row_number() over (order by settle_id) - 10 else row_number() over (order by settle_id) end as rowid,settle_id from student_id(nolock) 
select * from #tmp
drop table #tmp
```

I want row id should start from 1 -> 10 everytime but for first two sets it start from 1->10 but there after it starts with 11.
Please let me know what i am missing.

Comment: You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Added `sql-server` tag based on the `#tmp` and `top 100` syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below **query** to get the expected **result**.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN ((row_number() over(order by settle_id) % 10) = 0) 
     THEN 10 
     ELSE (row_number() over (ORDER BY settle_id) % 10)  
END AS  RowID, settle_id
FROM student
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using modulo arithmetic:

```
select ((row_number() over (order by settle_id) - 1) % 10) + 1 as rowid, settle_id
from student;
```

Some databases use the `mod()` function instead of `%`.

Comment: Above query start the rowid from 2 only.

Comment: so use -1 instead of +1 - apply some  basic mathematics!!

Comment: @Veera . . . `row_number()` starts at 1, but modulo starts returning at 0.  The solution is to subtract 1 and then add it back in.